# How to find ending index of substring where I don't know the exact string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have data being sent to me where I need to seek out and identify the ending index of the URL within the string. The one piece of information I have is that the URL will always start with "http". Using this information I can get the starting index. In the case of the example below, that is 13.

```
const exampleString = "Hemoglobin - https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/index.html"
const urlStart = exampleString.indexOf("http");
const urlEnd = ????????
```

Now I need to identify the end of the URL substring that is dynamic. I have to be able to identify the first instance of a space after the starting index of 13.

It's also worth noting that the URL substring will not always be at the end of the string.

I'm thinking this is a regex problem but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try last index of " "(a space) , make sure it bigger than the urlStart

or the index of first space after urlStart